# No path in references

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have a large desktop application with 178 project in it.
I switched the domain on my PC and did a get from TFS to a different root path but most of the references are now broken.
They have a yellow warning next to them and no path.

[image: Broken References]

The problem seems to be with both Nuget packages and system references. Strangely it seems to be intermittent, some package references and some system references are okay. The Dot Net Framework I am using is still in the same location

I have tried a package reinstall but that didn't work.

Has anyone come across this problem before who knows of any easy way to fix this that doesn’t involve deleting and adding them all again? Which does not work anyway.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Total red herring.
Turned out to be, I had not included the .nuget folder.